# Rest API Acess denied 403 for customers and orders

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, customer, rest-api

I am trying to get the products,customers and orders through REST Api. It's working for`api/rest/products` getting product collection. But unable fetch the customers `api/rest/customers` and orders `api/rest/orders` collection it shows Access denied - 403

Comment: Can you help me regard rest api customer getting error : https://snag.gy/MVINwS.jpg @Ansar

Comment: Check that you have selected "Customers" resource for your API user's role.

Answer (score 0):

Magento REST API. These three access levels are as follows:

1. Guest
2. Customer
3. Admin

**Guest:** This level has access only to public resources. eg. Retrive products, Retrive categories & Retrive products images

**Customer:** 
Customer can be a registered and logged in user. This type of user can have access only to its own resources as well as to public resources.

**Admin:** Admin can be the store owner. This type has full set of permissions

See more details click [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/permission_settings/permission_settings.html)